# outsourcing strtok() in function in c

Tags: c

I want to outsource a string operation to a function and then ask the results in main. This doesn't work, and I don't understand why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void splitRequest(char request[], char method[], char ressource[], char proto[]) {

    method = strtok(request, " ");
    ressource = strtok(NULL, " ");
    proto = strtok(NULL, " ");
    printf("\nResult:\n\nmethod:\t\t%s\nressource:\t%s\nproto:\t\t%s\n",method,ressource,proto);
}

int main()
{    
    char method[50], ressource[50], proto[50], request[50];
    memset(method, '\0', 50);
    memset(ressource, '\0', 50);
    memset(proto, '\0', 50);
    memset(request, '\0', 50);
    strcpy(request,"Get /index.htm HTTP/1.1");

    //rehash query
    splitRequest(request, method, ressource, proto);

    //check Results
    printf("\nResult:\n\nmethod:\t\t%s\nressource:\t%s\nproto:\t\t%s\n",method,ressource,proto);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the `splitRequest` function all the arguments are pointers. And more importantly they are *local variables*. So all changes to them (like making them point anywhere else) will only affect the local variable, nothing else.

The solution is to *copy* to the memory instead. Perhaps something like

```
char *temp;

if ((temp = strtok(request, " ")) != NULL)
{
    strcpy(method, temp);
}

// And so on...
```

---

A little elaboration about what I mean...

In C all function arguments are passed *by value*. That means their value is *copied* and the function only have a local copy of the value. Chaning the copy will of course not change the original value.

It is the same with pointers. When you call your `splitRequest` function the pointers you pass are copied. Inside the function the variable `method` (for example) is pointing to the memory of the array you defined in the `main` function. When you assign to this variable, like you do with

```
method = strtok(...);
```

you only modify the local variable, the local copy of the pointer. When the function returns the local variable `method` goes out of scope, and all changes to it are lost.

There are two solutions to this problem. One is to emulate pass by reference (something which C doesn't have, which is why it must be emulated), but that will not work as long as you have an array. Therefore the second and easiest solution: To *copy* to the memory pointed to by the local variable `method`, which is what I show above.

An important note though: When you call the `splitRequest` function, passing the arrays, the arrays themselves are not passed. Instead the arrays *decays* to a pointer to their first element, and inside the function the variables defined by the arguments are pointers and not arrays.

The call

```
splitRequest(request, method, ressource, proto);
```

is equal to

```
splitRequest(&request[0], &method[0], &ressource[0], &proto[0]);
```

And the function declaration

```
void splitRequest(char request[], char method[], char ressource[], char proto[])
```

is equal to

```
void splitRequest(char *request, char *method, char *ressource, char *proto)
```

So no the strings are not copied, only the pointers. Otherwise you would have gotten an error when assigning to the pointer, since you can't assign to arrays only copy to them.

Comment: Did I understand correctly, that *temp then becomes a pointer to some part in the local variable request? And further so, that the strings are all copied from main to splitRequest?

Comment: @Linz Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I think I've got the point now.

Answer (score 0):

Found another workaround even more effectiv:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void splitRequest(char request[], char **method, char **ressource, char **proto) {

    *method = strtok(request, " ");
    *ressource = strtok(NULL, " ");
    *proto = strtok(NULL, " ");
    printf("\nResult:\n\nmethod:\t\t%s\nressource:\t%s\nproto:\t\t%s\n",*method,*ressource,*proto);
}

int main()
{    
    char *method, *ressource, *proto, request[50];
    memset(request, '\0', 50);
    strcpy(request,"Get /index.htm HTTP/1.1");

    //rehash query
    splitRequest(&request, &method, &ressource, &proto);

    //check Results
    printf("\nResult:\n\nmethod:\t\t%s\nressource:\t%s\nproto:\t\t%s\n",method,ressource,proto);

    return 0;
}
```